# Visual studio cannot connect to windows IoT raspberry pi

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2015, remote-debugging, windows-10-iot-core, raspberry-pi3

I am using Windows Insider Build 14342 windows 10 OS. Trying to connect to raspberry pi 3. I have installed the Iot Core in Raspberry and I can connect to the device using putty and powershell. The visual studio for some reason doesnt deploy my Application.

Its a basic blink example from ms-iot github. I have set ARM, Remote device and gave ip address of the device, selected Universal(unencrypted protocol) in properties of the project.

The project builds fine and doesnt deploy to my device. Am i missing something.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem before one week. Here are steps I use to solve this issue:

1. Open Network and sharing Center.
2. click on your Ethernet connection
3. click property
4. Select IP4
5. Change your IP to be in same rang with your raspberry pi

After that your visual studio will able to detect your device automatically.